# Folder with nothing in it is still using up space

Tags: finder, hard-drive, folders, macos, space

I have a folder with absolutely nothing in it.  Zero.  I made sure there was no hidden files in it, by typing "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES." into my terminal.  There is nothing in the folder 100% and I've emptied my trashbin, yet it still shows this folder holding 188GBs of space.  I know I can delete the folder and get that space back, but I'm looking for the root of the issue.  Why is this happening and is this happening in other folders on my Mac El Capitan

Comment: in Terminal.app type `ls -al <pathway>` (for example `ls -al /Users/Sean/Documents/`) and put what it displays in the question. You can also use `cd <pathway>` to **c**hange **d**irectory and get the command prompt working in that particular directory (pathway) and then just type `ls -al`. A shift+cmd+4 then spacebar snapshot of the command+i information window for the folder in question would also help (`open ..` or `open <pathway>` from the Terminal to launch the window in the Finder... give the folders info window a bit to load the total size)

Comment: One cause of this behavior is that there is an open application that was using a file in the folder, and even though the file has been deleted, the application is still "holding onto" the file (and thus its space). This is often seen in the /tmp directory. Does the behavior persist after rebooting?